pyspark assumes more precision than orginal when reading from oracle
I am reading oracle table using pySpark. my oracle table contains data type NUMBER and it contains 35 digits long value. when I read this column using spark, it seems spark assumes more precision than original and end up in throwing following error:
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Decimal precision 45 exceeds max precision 38`

please note: I am inferring schema from spark dataframe as I don't want to explicitly pass schema.
when I try to printSchema() and df.show(), I am getting following.
root |-- add_digit_num: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true) 

WARN conf.HiveConf: [Thread-5]: HiveConf of name hive.masking.algo does not exist WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: [task-result-getter-1]: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) ( executor 1): java.lang.ArithmeticException: Decimal precision 45 exceeds max precision 38 

pyspark code below:
df_rdbms_data = spark.read.jdbc(url=source_jdbc_url, table=source_table_name, properties=source_properties)
df_rdbms_data.printSchema()
df_rdbms_data.show()

Is there any way to resolve this issue apart from not passing explicit schema?
Thanks in advance.

It would be best to explicitly mention the precision to the decimal column.

from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType


df = (
    spark.read.jdbc(
        url=source_jdbc_url,
        table=source_table_name,
        properties=source_properties
    )
)


decimal_columns_exceeding_precision = [
    (field.name, field.dataType.precision, field.dataType.scale)
    for field in df.schema.fields
    if isinstance(field.dataType, DecimalType) and field.dataType.precision > 38
]


for col_name, precision, scale in decimal_columns_exceeding_precision:
    df = df.withColumn(col_name, df[col_name].cast(DecimalType(38, scale)))
    print(f"Adjusted Column: {col_name}, Precision: 38, Scale: {scale}")


df.printSchema()

df.show()


PS: I did not test this code as I don't have Oracle db setup.

Is there any other way as I wont be knowing these column names prior to the ingestion ? I am ingesting 200+ tables from oracle and its difficult to pass explicit schema for all tables or by adding explicit casting

check now @BigD

the problem is as i mentioned in question my oracle table not exceeding precision 38. max length of my oracle table column is 35 only. that means it contains 35 digits maximum. still spark assume that column contains 45 precision and try to make decimal type beyond 38.

specfically when i try to printSchema and df.show(), I am getting following. root
|-- add_digit_num: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
WARN  conf.HiveConf: [Thread-5]: HiveConf of name hive.masking.algo does not exist
WARN  scheduler.TaskSetManager: [task-result-getter-1]: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) ( executor 1): java.lang.ArithmeticException: Decimal precision 45 exceeds max precision 38

can you try to prepare oracle select query based on df schema and pass it to new input df. that will push the casting to oracle and force spark dataframe have resulted schema.

you mean to say - first read oracle table and inferschema , save it in python variables and then again read oracle table by passing this saved shcema ?

Correct, warn: you are treating all the decimal column maximum to 38.

but if i pass decimal(38,10)  second time reading  i am getting same error as my oracle table contain 35 digit long number and for decimal(38,10) i can accommodate max 28 digits number and rest(10) for floating point number. The only way is I need to convert this decimal(38,10)  to StringType and pass this string type when second time reading . any opinion ?

in fact, converting to String is a good idea. you can try this roughly CAST(CAST(col_name AS STRING) AS DECIMAL)
